# Question Concerning Creating Specific Table

Tags: tables

Here is a table I would like to replicate (from David Griffith's book "Introduction to Elementary Particles", p. 49):

[image]

In particular, I would like to get the "First generation", "Second Generation" and "Third Generation" with brackets in my table as well as the caption "Lepton classification".

Here is my MWE (minimal-working example):

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|}
    \hline
    l & $Q$ &  $L_e$ & $L_{\mu}$ & $L_{\tau}$\\
    \hline
    $e$     & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    $\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0    \\
    \hline
    $\mu$     & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
    $\nu_{\mu}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    \\
    \hline 
    $\tau$     & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
    $\nu_{\tau}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1    \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With the help of the `bigdelim` and `multirow`packages, a `\multicolumn`command, two additional columns and `\clines`s:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{bigdelim}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{}r@{}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{0.6cm}|}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{5}{c}{Lepton classification}\\
    \cline{3-7}
    &&l & $Q$ &  $L_e$ & $L_{\mu}$ & $L_{\tau}$\\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{First generation} & \ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&$e$     & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    &&$\nu_e$ & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Second generation}& \ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&$\mu$     & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
    &&$\nu_{\mu}$ & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Third generation} &\ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&$\tau$     & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
    &&$\nu_{\tau}$ & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

With an `array` instead of a `tabular` and centered instead of fixed width columns:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{bigdelim}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \[
    \begin{array}{l@{}r@{}|c|c|c|c|c|}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}& \multicolumn{5}{c}{\text{Lepton classification}}\\
    \cline{3-7}
    &&l & Q &  L_e & L_{\mu} & L_{\tau}\\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{First generation} & \ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&e    & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
    &&\nu_e & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Second generation}& \ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&\mu     & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
    &&\nu_{\mu} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \multirow{2}{*}{Third generation} &\ldelim\{{2}{9pt}&\tau     & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
    &&\nu_{\tau} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1    \\
    \cline{3-7}
    \end{array}
    \]
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 surely. Peraphs for my humble opinion to have the numbers centered and fix the minus sign: see the original image.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Thanks. I didn't pay too close attention to the actual contents of the table itself. I will add an update.